# Adding order by with offset and limit in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM lead LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

to select data from the table lead and limit the results to 5 with offset of 0. I would like to order the results by its id by desc, so the results will be populated as the last added data first.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM lead LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0 order by id desc
```

but it's not working.  Please correct me where am wrong.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to

```
select * from lead order by id desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

The manual ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html ) describes that LIMIT is only allowed to appear after the ORDER BY.

Comment: As per the doc: **For compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL also supports the LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset syntax.**  `LIMIT x OFFSET y` is definitely more explicit and less confusing than `LIMIT x, y`.

Answer (score 7):

The `ORDER BY` clause should come before the `LIMIT` clause. This makes sense because you first want the record set to be ordered and then apply the limitation.

```
SELECT * FROM lead ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

You can use either `LIMIT offset, row_ count` syntax or the `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset`.

Check:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html